# SQL Server xml variable is not by reference

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, variables, reference

the following query should append node to an exist xml.
based on the output xml variable is actually new node and not reference of the exists one.
can I use reference variable
please advise:

```
declare @a_bo_key_xml xml='<r><items><item><key>k1</key><value>v1</value></item></items></r>'
Declare @rowsBOK xml=@a_bo_key_xml.query('/r/items/item')
select  @rowsBOK.value('(*/key)[1]','varchar(100)'), @rowsBOK.value('(*/value)[1]','varchar(100)')
set @rowsBOK.modify('insert <added>aaa</added> as first into (*)[1]') 
select cast(@a_bo_key_xml as varchar(max))
select cast(@rowsBOK  as varchar(max))
```

```
output:
<r><items><item><key>k1</key><value>v1</value></item></items></r>
<item><added>aaa</added><key>k1</key><value>v1</value></item>
```

```
expected:
<r><items><item><added>aaa</added><key>k1</key><value>v1</value></item></items></r>
<item><added>aaa</added><key>k1</key><value>v1</value></item>
```

Answer (score 0):

XML variables take a new identity when re-assigned, there is no connection between one and the other.

Just modify the `@a_bo_key_xml` variable directly:

```sql
declare @a_bo_key_xml xml='<r><items><item><key>k1</key><value>v1</value></item></items></r>';
set @a_bo_key_xml.modify('insert <added>aaa</added> as first into (/r/items/item)[1]');
select @a_bo_key_xml;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3e0844cd5694c4ffca1ff7c373046d01)

Comment: thanks , that what I suspected less efficient to work with the entire xml all the time

Comment: No, that's not how it works. Internally it is represented by IDs which can be seeked efficiently. Copying is certainly slower